Digital Signature Certificate using eforms produces unsigned signature field
I am almost certain that I am reproducing the Questions 1 - still let me post as I am not sure whether the package is being maintained.
The issue is that if I compile the following code it produces the PDF without any TeX error [in this case .pfx is produced using openssl 2 and resides in the same directory where the code is residing]. But when opened it using Adobe Reader it produces error like Unsigned signature field (Click to sign); under Digital Signature tab Foxit is also flashing the Unsigned Signature Fields. Same for Libre Office Draw and Okular (Could not verify Properly). I have also tried with the eformsman.pdf. I think there the sign file is D_P_Story.pfx and passkey is "dps017". But the similar errors are appearing in all the PDF viewers.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{eforms}
\usepackage{aeb_pro, docassembly}
\begin{docassembly}
\sigInfo{
    cSigFieldName:"mySig",
    ohandler:security.PPKLiteHandler,
    cert:"./xxx.pfx", 
    password:"XXX",
    oInfo:{
        location:"XX, XX",
        reason:"I am approving this document",
        contactInfo:"xxx@gmail.com",
        appearance:"My Signature" % only uncomment and set this if you actually have an appearance defined
    }
};
\signatureSign
\end{docassembly}
\begin{document}
Say Hi
\sigField[\BC{0 0 0}]{mySig}{2in}{4\baselineskip}
\end{document}

I am also kind of confused with the following:

When opening the PDF with Acrobat, the JavaScript code will be
imported from docassembly.fdf.

Do I need to share the docassembly.fdf everytime while sharing the produced pdf? That would make no sense though. Even if I am keeping the fdf and the produced pdf in the same directory it does not change the situation i.e. I cannot see the signature in any viewer.
Note: I have tested on Overleaf and my local Ubuntu texlive with latex version 3.14.

The author of the package has died and the packages are no longer maintained. If you want to get this working you have to install javascript files into some folder in acrobat. The files are now in the acrotex-js package on ctan and installation instructions are here https://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/acrotex-js/docs/install_jsfiles.pdf  There is no garanty that the instructions are still valid!

You should certainly not share the fdf - it contains your password. As far as I got the code/description you are meant to open the PDF in acrobat (or pass it through the distiller), it will the import the fdf with javascript and so sign the PDF and then you can save that. Personally I don't see really the point here. You could simply create an unsigned field, open in the reader and sign it.

Even if I properly install it, there are no guarantees the receiver of the document has the similar environment. @UlrikeFischer because you have commented here, I would like you to ask isn't there any universal way in LaTeX which can help in Signing PDF with digital certificates?

Not that I know of. It is trivial to add a signature field which you can sign in the reader which your certificate, but doing everything in LaTeX  including the actual signing is non-trivial as the signing process needs to know the size and byteranges of the final pdf, so this can probably be done only with luatex (if at all, context has an implementation, it was just described in tugboat, but they use luametatex). I would need a very good reason before I even start to look at this.

@UlrikeFischer If the reason happens to be an use-case will it suffice? I can share the one I am looking upon. I am trying to distribute offer letters (with some other reagents) which needs to be signed. But I fear if I use any foreign software for that it can overwrite the PDF Meta Data which will be crucial for us to keep intact.

Sorry but "I fear" is not enough. You can test what the reader does when signing a PDF. And you can check the metadata. Also: even if you convince me, I won't do it directly. If you need that now better use context.

@UlrikeFischer for having `a very good reason’, please find your comments in tx.sx repo: Question 1, Question 2, Question 3 one of which is at least 5 years old. All of which instead of providing solutions, only talking/committing/asking vaguely. I think wrt those ‘my fear’ was enough after testing through several apps.

All the questions you link to are about creating the field - that is easy and you can already do that with eforms or digsig. signing the field is the complicated part.
